# TypeError: instance.render is not a function white creating dynamic inputs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error 'TypeError: instance.render is not a function' white creating dynamic inputs in React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from '../../Ui/Input/Input';
class InputElements extends Component{
    state = {
        orderForm : {
            name: {
                elementType : 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type : 'text',
                    placeholder : 'Enter Your Name'
                },
                value : ''
            },
            email: {
                elementType : 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type : 'email',
                    placeholder : 'Enter Your E-Mail'
                },
                value : ''
            },
            street: {
                elementType : 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type : 'text',
                    placeholder : 'Street Name'
                },
                value : ''
            },
            postal: {
                elementType : 'input',
                elementConfig: {
                    type : 'number',
                    placeholder : 'Postal Code'
                },
                value : ''
            },
        },

    }
    return(){
        const formElementArray = [];
        for(let key in this.state.orderForm){
            formElementArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.orderForm[key]
            });
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    {formElementArray.map(formElement => (
                        <Input 
                            key={formElement.id}
                            elementtype={formElement.config.elementType}
                            elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
                            value={formElement.config.value} 
                        />
                    ))}
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InputElements;
```

Here I created Input Component.
I am getting this error 'TypeError: instance.render is not a function' white creating dynamic inputs in React. I dont know where the issue comes. 
I am getting this error 'TypeError: instance.render is not a function' white creating dynamic inputs in React. I dont know where the issue comes.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Input.css';

const Input = (props) => {
    let inputElement = null
    console.log(props)
    switch (props.elementtype){
        case ('input') : 
        inputElement = <input className='InputElement' {...props.elementConfig} value={props.value} />
        break;
        case ('textarea') : 
        inputElement = <textarea className='InputElement' {...props.elementConfig} value={props.value} />
        break;
        default :
        inputElement = <input className='InputElement' {...props.elementConfig} value={props.value} />
        break;
    }
    return (
        <div className='Input'>
            <label className='Lable'>{props.lable}</label>
            {inputElement}
        </div>
    )
}
export default Input;
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Class components require a `render` function, which you kind of have, but it's not called render. Instead, it's called `return`.

You need this: (notice that it says `render` as the method name).

```js
    render(){
        const formElementArray = [];
        for(let key in this.state.orderForm){
            formElementArray.push({
                id: key,
                config: this.state.orderForm[key]
            });
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    {formElementArray.map(formElement => (
                        <Input 
                            key={formElement.id}
                            elementtype={formElement.config.elementType}
                            elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
                            value={formElement.config.value} 
                        />
                    ))}
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

However, there are other problems here. Changing that method name will get your UI to display, but it won't update when anyone types in the fields. Your field data needs to be saved in some state somewhere. Right now, you have it set to be in the input elements class, but you aren't ever updating it. You need to update your state when the input fields change.

I would start with a simple component that holds state and a child component that can update that state to familiarize yourself with that mechanism before you dive into what you trying to accomplish above. Once you understand how states updates, it should be easy to see how this application should be structured.

Comment: Yes I need to update state dynamically when user update input fields. Thanks for your valuable reply @JeremyHenson